# How to fold C-style multiple-line comments /*...*/ in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have tried using the `foldmethod = syntax` but then if folds parentheses of functions and almost anything else but not multi-line comments. There is no foldlevel that does what I want. I want it to fold only multi-line comments. Unfortunately [this](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Fold_C-style_comments) function doesn't work anymore.

I also tried doing it as for single-line comments, but then it folds everything, althoug I have exaped the asterisk.

```
autocmd FileType cpp    setlocal foldmethod=expr foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)=~'^\\s*//'
autocmd FileType cpp    setlocal foldmethod=expr foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)=~'^\\s*/\*'
```

Normal regular expressions like this also don't work

```
/\\*.*?\\*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to *only* fold multi-line comments, then the following should be enough:

```
" in after/ftplugin/cpp.vim
setlocal foldmethod=marker
setlocal foldmarker=/*,*/
```

See `:help 'foldmethod'` and `:help 'foldmarker'`.